# Kendo window size issue in IE11 / Edge

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-window

I have a Kendo window that I populate with an MVC partial view. When I set the size to "auto", it renders correctly in Chrome, but looks terrible in IE11 and Edge. Specifically, the resulting window ends up being 56px x 1203px. In chrome, the same code generates a kendo window that is 1174px x 520px, which is much more usable.

When I set the size to be "large" or "medium" or "small", I get an acceptable result in IE/Edge (which is to say that it doesn't render a window that's incredible narrow and long). Of course, setting the height/width explicitly works as expected across both browsers.

Here's example code I'm using to initialize the window:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("wndSample")
    .Title("Add Sample")
    .Actions(actions => { actions.Close(); })
    .Draggable()
    .Resizable()
    .Modal(true)
    .Visible(false))
```

And code that I use to populate and open the window

```
$("#sp_wndSample").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Show progress indicator until window loads
        kendo.ui.progress($("#wndSample"), true);

        $("#wndSample").kendoWindow({
            refresh: function () {
                // progress off
                kendo.ui.progress($("#wndSample"), false);
            }
        });

        // populate 
        var m_dialog = $("#wndSample").data("kendoWindow");
        m_dialog.refresh('@Html.Raw(Url.Action("_SomePartialView","Some", new { pParam1UUID = Model.Param1UUID, pParam2 = "SomeValue" }))')
        m_dialog.setOptions({
            modal: true,
            size: "auto",
            position: {
                top: 70,
                left: 150
            }
        })
        m_dialog.title("Some Title");
        m_dialog.open();
    });
```

And on the off chance that this is really a CSS problem, here's a snippet from the custom CSS I'm using:

```
/* reset everything to the default box model */

*, :before, :after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/* set a border-box model only to elements that need it */

.form-control, /* if this class is applied to a Kendo UI widget, its layout may change */
.container,
.container-fluid,
.row,
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1,
.col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2,
.col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3,
.col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4,
.col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5,
.col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6,
.col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7,
.col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8,
.col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9,
.col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10,
.col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11,
.col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

Ideally I'd like to figure out why the kendo window is sized different in Chrome vs IE11/Edge and determine what changes are needed so that it sizes correctly (with size = "auto") on both browsers.

Comment: It can be related to the kendo window default animations. It was a known issue here https://www.telerik.com/forums/window-does-not-seem-to-center-correctly-in-ie-and-firefox-3-6

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried disabling animations, but it did not help. I also tried commenting out my custom stylesheet, and the problem still exists, so I'm leaning towards my CSS not being the culprit. Lastly, I'm on version 2019.2.619, for future reference.

Comment: After some more testing, I believe the issue is a conflict with Bootstrap v4, as when I disable that CSS stylesheet, the Kendo window sizes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..its work for me

```js
    var gridObj;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        gridObj = $('#gridName').getKendoGrid();
        gridAutoHeight(gridObj);
        resizeGrid();
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        gridAutoHeight(gridObj);
        resizeGrid();
    });
    function gridAutoHeight(gridObj, bottomMargin) {
        try {
            if (gridObj) {
                gridObj.element.height($(window).height() - gridObj.element[0].offsetTop - (110) - (bottomMargin || 120));
                gridObj.resize();
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error resizing grid: ' + e.toString());
        }
    }
    function resizeGrid() {
        var gridElement = $("#Gridrgrid");
        gridElement.data("kendoGrid").resize();
        setPageSize();
    }
    function setPageSize() {
        var grid = $("#gridName").data("kendoGrid");
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        //Custom Logic for pageSize
        if (windowHeight >= 900) {
            grid.dataSource.pageSize(100);
        }
        else if (windowHeight >= 800) {
            grid.dataSource.pageSize(70);
        }

        else if (windowHeight >= 700) {
            grid.dataSource.pageSize(50);
        }
        else if (windowHeight >= 500) {
            grid.dataSource.pageSize(40);
        }
        else if (windowHeight >= 400) {
            grid.dataSource.pageSize(30);
        } else {
            grid.dataSource.pageSize(20);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion, but my issue is with the Kendo window object, not the grid object. Your solution seems to be isolated to changing the height of Kendo grids.